# Regex User generated strings break match and replace function when strings contain chars needing escaping

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am taking user generated strings and matching/replacing them as needed. Something to the tune of

```
new RegExp(str,'gi')
```

If a user types in something like `[Hey` or `]` or something that would otherwise normally need to be escaped the code breaks. How can I work around this? is there a clean means of doing it?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you, I did.. it helped me over all solve the issue I was having. Don't know how many posts I went through prior to asking that didn't help.. anyway, thanks again!